# tablelayout edit text in column not covering full screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following layout file for my dialogue fragment. The problem is that edit text in table row layout are not of same width. I want them to cover the entire width on my dialogue screen. Also I want text boxes to take only 30% of dialogue screen width and 70% for edit texts. Can someone please help me with this ?

Following is the snapshot of my dialogue window !

[image: dialogue window]

Following is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>



<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:id="@+id/address_tab"
             android:stretchColumns="1"
             android:shrinkColumns="0"
             android:background="@color/white"

    >
    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@color/darkgreen"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:paddingTop="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_salutation"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:text="@string/per_salutation"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:id="@+id/per_edit_salutation"
            android:editable="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/text_job_title"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/per_job_title"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_edit_job_title"
            android:editable="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"

            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_first_name"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/per_first_name"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_edit_first_name"
            android:editable="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_last_name"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/per_last_name"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_edit_last_name"
            android:editable="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/text_country"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center|left"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="@string/per_suffix"/>


            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/suffix_spinner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:theme="@style/mySpinnerItemStyle"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/suffix_arrays"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                />




    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_begin_letter"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/per_begin_letter"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_edit_begin_letter"
            android:editable="true"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_letter_salut"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:text="@string/per_letter_salut"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/per_edit_letter_salut"
            android:editable="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            />
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_weight="1"
                      android:paddingTop="30dp"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_save_name_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dialog_box_positive_button"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_cancel_name_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:text="@string/dialog_box_negative_button"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableLayout positions its children into rows and columns. TableLayout containers do not display border lines for their rows, columns, or cells. The table will have as many columns as the row with the most cells. **A table can leave cells empty, but cells cannot span column**s, as they can in HTML

you can use android:layout_weight="1" for Edit Text

http://androidexample.com/Table_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=74&aaid=98

Comment: thanks for your response. I am unable to understand that why edit text is not spanning to the whole column width of 2nd column in each row. Even if I use android:layout_weight="1" it covers the whole second column only when there is a value in that edit text box that covers the entire width of 2nd column. However, if there is no value in the edit text edit text width is almost invisible.